# EF Core: Using ID as Primary key and foreign key at same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-model-builder

I have two entities, `Prospect` and `Person`, what I'm trying to do is use `Prospect.ID` as the primary key on `Prospect` table and as the foreign key of `PersonID`, my idea is use the same ID for both entities without the need of a `PersonID` on my `Prospect` entity. When the prospect is being saved on database, it tries to save a `PersonID` even though I don't have this property on my `Prospect` entity, I would like to know if EF core supports this kind of relationship.

Here's what I got on my model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProspectDto>(builder => { builder.ToTable("Prospects"); builder.HasKey(prospect => prospect.ID); });

modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDto>(builder => { builder.HasOne(p => p.Prospect).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ProspectDto>(pe => pe.ID); });
```

Here's what is being executed on database:

```
INSERT INTO [Prospects] ([ID], [PersonID]) VALUES (@p421, @p422)
```

`PersonDto`:

```
public class PersonDto : DtoBase
{
    public PersonDto()
    {
        
    }
  
    public ProspectDto Prospect { get; set; }
}
```

`ProspectDto`:

```
public class ProspectDto : DtoBase
{
    public ProspectDto()
    {

    }

    public PersonDto Person { get; set; } = new PersonDto();
}
```

`DtoBase`:

```
public abstract class DtoBase
{
    public Guid ID { get; protected set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please show `ProspectDto` and `PersonDto` class declaration (you may skip data fields, not related to question).

Comment: @Dmitry Updated

Comment: Hmm, can't see any `ID` field... Guess it may exist in `DtoBase`... Can you please provide all info about your model, related to question?

Comment: @Dmitry Updated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using attributes only, without FluentAPI:

```
public abstract class DtoBase
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; protected set; }
}

public class PersonDto : DtoBase
{
    [InverseProperty("Person")]
    public ProspectDto Prospect { get; set; }
}

public class ProspectDto : DtoBase
{
    [ForeignKey("ID")]           // "magic" is here
    public PersonDto Person { get; set; } = new PersonDto();
}
```

I don't know what is equivalent of `ForeignKey` in FluentAPI. All other (Key and InverseProperty) are configurable, but why use two methods instead one.

Code above generates following migration code:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Persons",
        columns: table => new
        {
            ID = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Persons", x => x.ID);
        });

    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Prospects",
        columns: table => new
        {
            ID = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Prospects", x => x.ID);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_Prospects_Persons_ID",
                column: x => x.ID,
                principalTable: "Persons",
                principalColumn: "ID",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        });
}
```

Looks very close to what you need.

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. Other question, do you know the equivalent of this using fluent API?

Comment: Surprised not more upvotes on this - works perfectly and is a clear example.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I prefer attributes instead of FluentAPI.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the FluentAPI equivalent of @dmitry's solution:

```
// Model classes:
public abstract class DtoBase
{
    public Guid ID { get; protected set; }
}

public class PersonDto : DtoBase
{
    public ProspectDto Prospect { get; set; }
}

public class ProspectDto : DtoBase
{
    public PersonDto Person { get; set; } = new PersonDto();
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------

// DbContext's OnModelCreating override:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProspectDto>().HasOne(p => p.Person).WithOne().HasForeignKey<ProspectDto>(p => p.ID);
}
```

Comment: Dominik, you have forgotten .Entity<ProspectDto>() after modelBuilder. Then it works well. So, I'll vote up after fixing... ;-)

Comment: @Tolbxela you are right, thank you! Just fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

If you model the relationship as one:one, EF will automatically use the PK of the principal as FK for the dependent.

```
 ModelBuilder.Entity<ProspectDto>().HasRequired(p => p.Person).WithRequiredDependent();
```

Please note that `ProspectDto` will still have an `ID` column on the DB (inherited from DtoBase), but the FK relationship will be between `ProspectDto.ID` and `PersonDto.ID` and there should be no `ProspectDto.PersonId` column.

Comment: HasRequired() is not available on ef core.

Comment: Sorry, should have read your question more carefully, this code is from an EF 6.1 project.